# How to use Active power save mode in ControlExtension

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

Could somebody help me to get Active power save mode of Smartwatch 2 working?

I would like to change the SampleControlExtension from SDK 2.0 to use low power support, but it seems to be ignored. How do I completely turn of the backlight in Smartwatch 2 like in the Watchface to allow longer battery lives?

Comment: Did u find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The SmartWatch 2, and the current emulator version, does not currently support low power through the Smart Extension APIs, but it will be added in the near future. I will try to update in this thread when it is fully available!

Answer (score 0):

Low power mode is available in recent SW2 firmware. 
Just add following override method to your RegistrationInformation class(your class must inherit base class from SmartExtensionUtils):

```
@Override
public boolean supportsLowPowerMode() {
    return true;
}
```

In low power mode extension doesn't stop when screen off by timeout. Extension will be displayed in monochrome mode.